# MSWord table shading prints too dark

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2010

My friend has a very light shading in his MSWord tables. However they still print too dark to read the text. When emailed to a colleague using the same printer, it prints light nicely. However they cannot find any setting that is different between them. Any ideas? Thanks!

(P.s. for myself this would help for non-tables also, when 'highlighting' text. I do know that 'shading' gives more colour options for non-tables, but it would be nice to know anyway. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! My colleague fixed it by re-adding his printer from the network.

Control panel, devices and printers, add a printer: He added the same printer again and set it as the default one. The ‘server name’ part of the printer name changed a bit. Both printers now lie there, but he set the newer name as his default printer. I guess some settings were updated by the company or something.

Apparently in MS Word, one must also make sure that file, options, advantaged, compatibility options, (at very bottom), layout options, print colours as black for non-colour printers = false. But it should be so already.